# Symmetric Key Encryption is not Authentication?

Tags: authenticated-encryption, chosen-ciphertext-attack

Is there any way to show CCA-secure symmetric-key encryption does not have to be an authenticated encryption?

I know you can create a set up that isn't authenticated, but how will you go about it?

Answer (score 2):

Consider a CCA2 secure secret key encryption scheme $\mathcal{E}$ with an exponentially large randomness space. Turn this into an encryption scheme $\mathcal{E'}$ where we extend the randomness space of $\mathcal{E}$ with one more element. Let's think of it as $0$ (we can get there by rearranging the randomness space). For randomness $0$ the encryption in $\mathcal{E'}$ becomes the identity for every element.

Now, I claim $\mathcal{E'}$ is still CCA secure as the probability that for the challenge query randomness 0 is chosen is negligible. However, $\mathcal{E'}$ is not a secure MAC as everybody knows a valid tag for any message.

Comment: Two comments/nitpicks: 1. You don't need to add an additional randomness value, you can just repurpose an existing one (e.g. the all 0 string). 2. For that scheme to be be complete you need to mark from which mode of the scheme the ciphertext resulted. You can do that e.g. by prefixing actual encryptions with 0 and the identity with 1.

Comment: True. While 1. i just an efficiency improvement, 2. is indeed necessary to allow for decryption of the added ciphertexts.